# What kind of bathroom shower handle should I get?

Tags: shower, bathroom-fixtures

My bathroom shower handle needs replacement -- it started falling off recently.  It's damaged and needs replacement.

What kind of a handle would work?

Below is how the rest of it looks like.  Note that I don't know the brand, it's not written anywhere.  Nor do I know which year it was produced.

[image]

[image]

Edit: here are pictures of the handle itself:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that the outer hex bolt is stuck (sitting for hours in WD-40, no success turning it after that).  I might be wrong, but I think there are two inner bolts on either side of the inner square piece.  One is stuck, the other is missing entirely.

I tried multiple handles from the hardware store and none of them really worked.

Comment: Could you please post a picture of the handle?

Comment: That does look a lot like some Delta models.

Comment: why is the handle falling off? ... are you sure that it is not a case of a loose screw?

Comment: I updated my questions with:
1) pictures of the handle
2) why the handle is falling - looks like one of the screws may be missing but there's no way to fix that.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it see picture of the handle in my updated post.

Comment: @jsotola does my update answer the question of why it was falling?

Comment: @MichaelKaras still looks like a Delta after I posted pics of the handle itself?

Comment: Yeah. Looks like a Delta. But as you can imagine there are dozens of manufacturers who all  introduce new styles and models every year or two. That means there are thousands of styles out there. Take a look at the Delta web site to browse their current lineup. Your challenge is a handle that uses a set screw, has same diameter hole and works at the hemisphere shaped end of the valve body.

Comment: The assembly and valve mechanism is very much like a Delta; however, a Delta handle would have only a single set screw. Hmmm... I am still betting Delta but older style. Check your plumbing shop (not Big Box) and bring the old handle, look for a Delta lever handle. It might not look identical to yours but I'll bet a sawbuck that it works.

Comment: Already went to a number of hardware stores and tried a number of handles without much luck.  I don't know how old it is but it's at least 10-11 years old...

Would an adaptor help?  Something like this?  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000DZH99W

@JimmyFix-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, in case others are struggling with this, I ended up using this:

[image]

It is a LASCO HL-50 Metal Lever Handle and fits Valley Brand (which is, per what what someone advised me offline, my bathroom shower handle is)

They sell it at Amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FHBIQS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FHBIQS)